# Excluding rows in update SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update a certain selection of rows with specific information.  This means that I cannot do a simple update statement but instead will have to specify the rows I want to change and the values by which I will amend them.  In short, I want to update a column of dates that are currently null against the corresponding parameterid; The following statement thus seems logical:

```
UPDATE contactparameter  
SET effectiveto = CASE parameterid    
When '2887' Then '13-Aug-2012'  
When '2896' Then '21-Feb-2012'   
When '3008' Then '28-Oct-2012'   
When '3272' Then '18-Jan-2013'   
END
```

If I then update, ALL the rows that are not included in this list, i.e. all rows where parameterids are NOT '2887', '2896', '3008' or '3272', are then emptied out.  I have tried selecting the rows I want to be updated in a sub query:

```
UPDATE contactparameter   
SET effectiveto = CASE parameterid   
When '2887' Then '13-Aug-2012'   
When '2896' Then '21-Feb-2012'   
When '3008' Then '28-Oct-2012'   
When '3272' Then '18-Jan-2013'   
END   
WHERE exists
    (SELECT cp.parameterid   
        from contact c   
       INNER JOIN contactparameter cp on c.serialnumber = cp.serialnumber   
       WHERE cp.effectivefrom is not null  
        and cp.effectiveto is null)
```

But this does exactly the same.  I am still fairly inexperienced in using SQL and I'm sure that I am missing a crucial element somewhere.  Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE contactparameter   
SET effectiveto = CASE parameterid   
   When '2887' Then '13-Aug-2012'   
   When '2896' Then '21-Feb-2012'   
   When '3008' Then '28-Oct-2012'   
   When '3272' Then '18-Jan-2013'   
END   
from contact c   
INNER JOIN contactparameter cp on c.serialnumber = cp.serialnumber   
WHERE cp.effectivefrom is not null  
and cp.effectiveto is null
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  This seems is the same as my second solution, which results in all rows being updated.  Do you know why this would be?

Comment: I've tried this again with using an additional parameter - cp.parametercategory which limits the rows being updated to what I want.  Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this,

#1, specify an ELSE clause in your CASE expressions to just return that same value that it already has, because otherwise it returns NULL to all of the non-matches:

```
UPDATE contactparameter  
SET effectiveto = CASE parameterid    
When '2887' Then '13-Aug-2012'  
When '2896' Then '21-Feb-2012'   
When '3008' Then '28-Oct-2012'   
When '3272' Then '18-Jan-2013'   
Else effectiveto
END
```

or, #2, use a WHERE clause to match only those rows that also have a match in your CASE expression:

```
UPDATE contactparameter  
SET effectiveto = CASE parameterid    
When '2887' Then '13-Aug-2012'  
When '2896' Then '21-Feb-2012'   
When '3008' Then '28-Oct-2012'   
When '3272' Then '18-Jan-2013'   
END
WHERE parameterid IN('2887','2896','3008','3272')
```

The second one is usually faster and preferred for locking reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  However, when performing the first solution it results in ALL rows being updated.  When using the second solution I get the following message "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Sorry, the second query has been fixed.  And yes, the first query updates the same rows as your original query, but does not blank the non-matching ones.